# GraphFrames connected components - Component Zero

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx, graphframes

When I run connected components algorithm on GraphFrames, there is a huge component with the component id of zero - 0.

What is that component?

Comment: I am afraid this is a bug in connected components algorithm. I read about inconsistent results in this algorithm and I think it is what happening in my case. There is no node with 0 value, so what so you think the meaning of this? The link to the bug: https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/159